# No commands matching with 'Enable Custom CSS and JS'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to add a theme to my VS CODE and i needed to run the command: `Enable Custom CSS and JS` in the ctrl+shift+P. But when I type it, it says that there are no commands matching. Is there another way to do it?

I added the import in the settings.json like:

```
"vscode_custom_css.imports": [
      "directoy/to/css"
]
```

but I can't apply.

Answer (score 0):

From the [extension's doc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css):

> **VERY IMPORTANT**: Items in `vscode_custom_css.imports` must be URLs. **Plain file paths are NOT URLs**.
>
> Windows File URL Example: `file:///C:/Users/MyUserName/Documents/custom.css`
>
> The `C:/` part is **REQUIRED**.
>
> MacOS and Linux File URL Example: `file:///Users/MyUserName/Documents/custom.css`
>
> ## Windows users
>
> In Windows, make sure you run your VS Code in Administrator mode before enabling or disabling your custom style!
>
> ## Mac and Linux users
>
> The extension would NOT if Code cannot modify itself. The cases include:
>
> - Code files being read-only, like on a read-only file system or,
> - Code is not started with the permissions to modify itself.
>
> You need to claim ownership on Code's installation directory, by running this command:
>
> ```
> sudo chown -R $(whoami) <Path to Code>
> ```
>
> The placeholder  means the path to VSCode installation. It is typically:
>
> `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron`, on MacOS;
>   `/Applications/Visual Studio Code - Insiders.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron`, on MacOS when using Insiders branch;
>
> `/usr/share/code`, on most Linux;
>
> `/opt/visual-studio-code/` on Arch Linux.
>
> Mac and Linux package managers may have customized installation path. Please double check your path is correct.